# Как вы ведете работы по сайту после посадки на CMS?

Tags: веб-программирование, modx

Я новичек в работе с CMS MODX Revolution, поэтому мой вопрос возможно детский.
Мое рабочее окружение состоит из редактора PHPStorm и таск-раннера Gulp.
Готовый проект собирается в папку app.
Итак, проект готов, я установил на него MODX, прописал все чанки, TV-поля и так далее. 
А как после этого работать с проектом, если нужно средствами IDE какие-то изменения внести?
Работать уже непосредственно с продакшен-версией сайта, на которую посажен MODX?
То есть, отпадает Gulp и т.д.
Или как?
Или вносить изменения в мою рабочую версию проекта, и после этого повторно натягивать админку?
Я надеюсь понятно что именно вызывает у меня затруднения. Скорее всего я просто чего-то не догоняю так как еще не проходил этот этап.
Очень надеюсь на развернутый ответ, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

После того как все нужные `чанки/сниппеты/шаблоны` вы создали, их можно вынести в любую необходимую директорию и связать с помощью галочки *"Статичный"* *(которая доступна при редактировании)*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, у нас есть чанк `header`.
Создаем в корне к примеру: `/tpl/chunks/header.tpl` и содержимое чанка помещаем в созданный файл. Затем связываем с нашим  чанком через вышеуказанную галочку *"Статичный"*

Тоже самое и со *сниппетами, шаблонами..*